# Is it bad practice to access a view in doInBackground()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-threading

Is it bad practice to pass a UI element, such as a `TextView`, to [`AsyncTask.doInBackground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) (through `AsyncTask.execute()`) and to *read* fields from the view in the background thread? (I know it's not okay to alter GUI elements from a background thread.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not great, for the simple reason that you do not know if that widget is any good anymore.

Suppose the following happens:

- You execute the `AsyncTask`, but it is stuck behind other tasks and does not run right away
- The user rotates the screen, or presses BACK, or otherwise destroys the activity
- Your `AsyncTask` finally starts running and you try accessing this widget

In the best-case scenario, the widget is simply wrong. In the worst-case scenario, whatever you call on it causes some sort of crash, because the hosting activity is destroyed.

`AsyncTask` itself is fairly obsolete; modern Android development uses other things (`LiveData`, RxJava, and Kotlin coroutines being the biggest candidates). However, if you wish to use `AsyncTask`, please ensure that it does not try referencing the activity or its widgets from `doInBackground()`.